# md-checkbox single check in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have problem on md-checkbox.
I need to use single selection of check but I couldn't make it.
I referred md-radio-button for groupings but I don't want to use radio button.

Below is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <md-checkbox ng-model="data1"  aria-label="Checkbox 1">
            Full Time
        </md-checkbox>
    </li>
    <li>
        <md-checkbox ng-model="data2" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
            6AM - 12 PM
        </md-checkbox>
    </li>
    <li>
        <md-checkbox ng-model="data3" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
            12PM - 9PM
        </md-checkbox>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `md-radio-group` functionality but with checkboxes.

To achieve this you can use `ng-true-value`, `ng-false-value` and a change handler (to make sure atleast one checkbox is checked):

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="data" ng-true-value="'data1'" ng-false-value="false" ng-change="!data && (data='data1')">
```

Here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/d2fev8ey/33/

Comment: Excellent Thank you

Comment: @Santhosh Welcome! :) Can you also upvote or atleast accept my answer?

Comment: @Santhosh I think you are new on StackOverflow... Here you are supposed to accept the answer which worked for you... So I am not asking for a favour.... I am asking for what I deserve...

Comment: Hi Devansh i can't upvote because as i am new to stackoverflow. Thanks i will update when i got reputation in this account.

Comment: @Santhosh but you can still accept the answer if not upvote because you are the asker... Give it a try... If it doesn't work let me know...

Comment: ya i made it thanks.Do you know photobox js.Have you worked on it.I am facing problem in it.

Comment: @Santhosh Np... I don't know about photobox.js but I might be able to solve your problem... If you want you ask a new question and send me this link of question so that I can check it when I am free...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087952/photobox-js-not-working-when-we-have-different-gallery-of-same-imagelinks-in-the

Comment: can you check above link

Comment: Ok... Np... Make sure you delete or update your question so that other people don't waste their time on it...

Comment: yes you are right!.I am updating it.Thanks.how can i do personnal chat with you.

Comment: Np... There's no need to chat with me personally... Just put up the question... And hopefully the StackOverflow community will help you out :)